# curl_multi_init with different proxy for each handle?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, curl-multi, proxies

i want to write a script using `curl_multi_init()` but i must have to specify the `curl_setopt()` with my proxy only once and not for each handle, there is a way to solve this with different proxy for each handle?

---

i got the solution, specify the proxy that you want with a new `curl_init()` then add a new handle.

```
$master = curl_multi_init();
$curl_arr[1] = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_arr[1], CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[1]);
do {
 curl_multi_exec($master,$running); //while there are running connections just keep looping
 } while($running > 0);
$data = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[1]);
```

and ect.